# what's the meaning of "iggly plops"?

Tags: meaning

> Without even looking at the book, she knew that the picture on the front was of a tiny little man standing on a leaf. When would Jumbeelia, who was nearly ning and perfectly capable of reading a book to herself, grow out of these babyish bedtime stories about **the iggly plops**? - The Giants and the Joneses of Julia Donaldson

I couldn't find proper meaning for 'iggly'.

plops means something like sound. It doesn't make sense.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The

> **iggly plops**

are  fictitious group of small people in a land of giants.  Julia Donaldson is a brilliant children's story writer having authored *The Gruffalo*. I have not read *The Giants and the Joneses* myself so do not know the original of the name **iggly plops**.

A brief synopsis

> Having heard all the stories about the **iggly plops** who ventured into the giants' land, a curious young giantess decides to travel down to their land for a surprise visit and, after capturing three iggly plops, returns home with her prize and awaits to hear the great tales her new friends are sure to have.

One of the reviews of the book

> "*The Giants and the Joneses* had humour, suspense and an **invented language** that enthralled me." "--The Evening Standard "(London)

Comment: I also think it's important to note that  children's stories often use nonsense words. [Professor Maria Nikolajeva claims that nonsense words help children understand the expressive power of language](http://www.cam.ac.uk/news/of-heffalumps-hunny-and-woozles) and the importance of linking meanings to words.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't understand a brief synopsis, though. Anyways all Americans know the word even though it doesn't exist in a dictionary, right?

Comment: Americans don't know the word, since it is a nonsense word made up by the author. However when reading the book it is clear from the context that the word mean "Human children" in the (fictional) language of the Giants called "Groilish". You can see a Groilish-English dictionary http://www.juliadonaldson.co.uk/groilish.pdf

Comment: @TingChoe  Not at all.  If the author makes up a word we have to figure out the meaning from context each time, for example J K Rowling's use of "muggle" to mean "non-magical person" in her "Harry Potter" books, which as well as perhaps *thousands* of other made-up words.